# How to concat dot(.) to string like pic.jpeg in mysql triggers?

Tags: mysql, laravel, triggers, database-trigger

I am getting this error

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '.' in 'field list.'

Code:

```
NEW.student_img_name = CONCAT(NEW.student_roll_no,'.',
                              (SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.student_img_name, `.`, -1)))
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about your configuration and what you are trying to do?

Comment: backticks are not the same as quotes,use in your SUSBTRING_INDEX quotes for `.` ,not backticks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NEW.student_img_name = CONCAT(NEW.student_roll_no,'.',
                             (SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.student_img_name, '.', -1)))
```

Try this? Maybe the error showing up is not the First dot, but the second one in SUBSTRING_INDEX.